# Not able to select a default value for DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not able to select dropdown value by default.

Title property of model has **Mr.**. But dropdown does not select it.

cshtml-

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Title)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, @ViewBag.All_Title as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

CS code-

```
ViewBag.All_Title = Titles(model.Title);
```

Titles method-

```
public static SelectList Titles(string selectedValue)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> titles = new List<SelectListItem>();

        titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Prof.", Value = "Prof." });
        titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dr.", Value = "Dr." });
        titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" });
        titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr.", Value = "Mr." });
        titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs.", Value = "Mrs." });
        titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms.", Value = "Ms." });

        SelectList sl = new SelectList(titles, "Value", "Text");//, selectedValue);
        return sl;
    }
```

Model is-

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Title")]
public string Title { get; set; }
public SelectList All_Title { get; set; }
```

**Update**

The debugger shows 'Mr.' is selectedValue but it does not remain selected on the webpage.

Comment: have you tried like this `titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms.", Value = "Ms." }.Selected)`

Comment: this will make code static. So I can't use this option. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("All_Title", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

### UPDATE

You need to keep your selected item Id in your model:

**Titles Method:**

```
public static SelectList Titles(string selectedValue)
{
    List<SelectListItem> titles = new List<SelectListItem>();

    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Prof.", Value = "1" });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dr.", Value = "2" });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss.", Value = "3" });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr.", Value = "4" });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs.", Value = "5" });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms.", Value = "6" });

    SelectList sl = new SelectList(titles, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
    return sl;
}
```

**Model:**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Title")]
public string Title { get; set; }
public int All_Title_Id { get; set; }
```

**Controller:**

```
ViewBag.All_Title_Id = Titles(model.Title);
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("All_Title_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: That will render as - <select name="All_Title"> which will give problem at the of POST request

Comment: Then use `ViewBag.Title = Titles(model.Title);` instead of `ViewBag.All_Title = Titles(model.Title);`

Comment: or you can manually set `name` value: `@Html.DropDownList("All_Title", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", name =  "Title" })`

Comment: Using above code, even if name is specified manually. It renders name="All_Title"

Comment: If you set `ViewBag.Title = Titles(model.Title);` then use `@Html.DropDownList("Title", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })` it will set `name="Title"`.

Comment: That is not working since the model already has Title property. And it is of type System.String

Comment: What type is your view model?

Comment: Why you keeping whole `SelectList` with your model?

Comment: Just for populating in View. I am testing many ways but it is not working.

Comment: SelectListItem does not have property ID. Have you tested your new update? I'm not able to use it

Answer (score 0):

we use this one in our project.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Client.ID, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "ID", "Name", Model.Client), "- All -", new { @class = "projects-drop-down", @id = "clientListDropDown"})
```

So, your dropdown should be like this one

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(ViewBag.All_Title, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.YourSelectListItemProperty), "- Select -", new { @class = "projects-drop-down", @id = "clientListDropDown"})
```

Comment: Nothing. The result should be the selected value-"Mr.". But I always get first value "Prof." selected.

Comment: did u try, selected = selected

Comment: Didn't understand what is this?

Comment: titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr.", Value = "Mr.", Selected = Selected}); correct the syntex where needed

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
public static SelectList Titles(string selectedValue)
{
    List<SelectListItem> titles = new List<SelectListItem>();

    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Prof.", Value = "Prof." });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dr.", Value = "Dr." });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss" });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mr.", Value = "Mr.", Selected = true });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mrs.", Value = "Mrs." });
    titles.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Ms.", Value = "Ms." });

    SelectList sl = new SelectList(titles, "Value", "Text");//, selectedValue);
    return sl;
}
```

Comment: This will make the code static. I am setting this value based on the value stored in the db

Comment: @kamalpreet so, if there is already a record/user in the database.. say for 'Mr. John Doe' and when that user goes to, let's say the *Edit* view.. the dropdown box for Title automatically goes to 'Prof'. since that is the first value in your selectlist and not 'Mr.'?

Comment: Yes. it is not selecting Mr.

Comment: @kamalpreet is this MVC?

Comment: @kamalpreet why can't you create a table in your database that holds all of those titles and then that table will hold the `ID` of the table where the person's name is in a foreign key?